# can supervisord be used for memory and CPU usage profiling of a program

Tags: c, unix, memory-leaks, profiling, supervisord

I have to find if running a particular api repeatedly over a period of time cause memory leak.

I have a simple C program which is used to test the API once. I am planning to compile it and run the exe using supervisord repeatedly.

Can supervisord also profile the program's CPU and memory usage? 
I searched extensively in several blogs but did not find much information on profiling ability of supervisord.

More about supervisor at http://supervisord.org

Comment: Without knowing more about the API you are testing I can't be sure that the OS won't leak memory on its behalf, but for most APIs when your "test the API once" program exits the OS will reclaim all memory allocated on behalf of that program and the leak will not be apparent.  You probably need to repeatedly test the API within the same process to get what you are looking for.  _valgrind_ was build for exactly this type of thing. I suggest you look into it.

Comment: Or maybe you are running a daemon and have a separate API that the test program is exercising (?)

Answer (score 6):

It can, see [Supervisod Event Listeners](http://supervisord.org/events.html?highlight=memmon) and [Superlance](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/superlance). I've had issues with supervisord leaking memory itself. [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/) can easily monitor memory and CPU and doesn't use a lot of resources.

Comment: If I use Monit to monitor Supervisord, who monitors Monit?